# Hibernate validator @NotEmpty not working spring boot and jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, hibernate-validator, spring-restcontroller

I have the following class which has errorRequests with @NotEmpty annotation.

```
public class ErrorsRequests implements Serializable {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = -727308651190295062L;

  private String applicationName;

  @NotEmpty
  @Valid
  @JsonProperty("errors")
  private List<ErrorsRequest> errorRequests;
```

My Controller looks like the following:

```
 @Autowired
  @Qualifier("errorStreamValidator")
  private Validator errorStreamValidator;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> errorReporting(@NotNull @PathVariable String applicationName,
      @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody ErrorsRequests errorsRequests, BindingResult results) {
```

I have the required hibernate validator classes in my classpath.

When I input the following JSON :

```
{
"errorss": [ 
  ]
}
```

The @NotEmpty validation is not kicked off at all. Hibernate validation only works if the json has errors element in it as below

```
 {
    "errors": [ 
      ]
    }
```

Can I make the first case also work ?

Comment: tried with @NotBlank as well that also doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

You are using the annotations in the wrong way and your controller is also missing an annotation.

You should annotate your controller with @Validated:

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mycontroller")
public class MyController { ... }
```

And in your model class you need to place the annotations like this:

```
@NotEmpty
private List<@Valid Foo> foo;
```

The @Valid annotation will check if the items inside the list are also valid.

Comment: If the foo value was not a List would you need a @Valid annotation?

Comment: Yes. The `@Valid` is verifying the Foo type, not the list. The validation for the list is `@NotEmpty`.

Comment: Hey @Prabhakar D. If the answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you have included this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```